# Specific CanCan Abilities for Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rails-admin

I am trying to manage some permission in my RailsAdmin, but am having trouble getting it to do exactly what I want to.

Using the ability file I have some set up. I want to be able to allow a specific kind of user to create, read, trash, export a particular model.

I decided to change:

```
can :manage, Terms, company_id: company_id
```

to:

```
can [:create, :read, :trash, :export], Terms, company_id: company_id
```

thinking that it would still show the little "info" and "delete" icons removing the "edit" icon. Instead it just shows the "info" icon.

I want the pencil to be gone. Any help or guidance is appreciated. I looked at the cancan page and didn't get much help.

**Original:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: after]

Comment: CanCanCan is better mantained.

Answer (score 0):

Below:

```
can :manage, Terms, company_id: company_id
```

I added:

```
cannnot :update, Terms, company_id: company_id
```

which seemed to work properly